# Is a UTF-16 string whose length in bytes is not divisible by two always invalid?

Tags: unicode, utf-16

If you have a UTF-16 string whose length in bytes is for example 21. Is it safe to say right away that this string has invalid UTF-16 in it? I am not counting in the null-terminator here. I am just counting the actual text data. My reasoning is that in UTF-16 text elements are encoded as 1 or 2 two-byte sequences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **yes, of course**. As you said,

> UTF-16 text elements are encoded as 1 or 2 two-byte sequences.

One half of a two-byte sequence is always invalid.

But beware: you say that you are “not counting in the null-terminator here”. But there cannot be a single-byte null-terminator in UTF-16, because a single `0x00` byte can be the least significant byte of a valid UTF-16 byte pair. E.g., the character Ā, called “Latin Capital Letter A with macron” is Unicode `U+0100`, i.e., the byte sequence `0x00 0x01` in UTF-16LE (little endian) or `0x01 0x00` in UTF-16BE (big endian).

Comment: OK, good. I just wanted to make sure. Good point about the null terminator. If for some reason you have to read sequence of bytes that represent UTF-16 and you don't know how many text elements to read you must continue to scan until you find two adjacent zero bytes not just one so that you don't stop reading too early. Or when passing UTF-16 to some API that read's the string until null terminator then you must include the two zero bytes at the end so that it doesn't go too far or read in some garbage or cause a crash or something else bad.

Comment: "*if ... you don't know how many text elements to read you must continue to scan until you find two adjacent zero bytes*" - make sure you look for 2 adjacent null bytes at a proper multiple-of-2 byte offset. You don't want to mistake the trailing null of one codeunit and the leading null of the next codeunit as a null terminator. You have to scan 2 bytes at a time, looking for a complete codeunit that is 0 by itself. And make sure it is not part of a surrogate pair, as that would also indicate a malformed sequence.